# Is there a whole list of STL algorithms?

Tags: c++

Is there a whole list of STL algorithms? The one on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm does not include for example `std::distance()` defined in `<iterator>`. Or `std::distance()` is not part of the STL?

Comment: You need to define what an "STL algorithm" is.

Comment: There is a list of [Standard-Library headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header). Not all functions are inside the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: std::distance is defined in `<iterator>` so it is documented in [other place](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator).

Comment: STL (HP _Software Technology Lab_) has since somewhat changed when incorporated into the standard, and also greatly expanded since it was proposed to the standards committee.  There is no one header that encompasses everything that it once comprised, nor currently has grown to become.

Comment: @michalt38 Geeks for Geeks doesn't have a particularly good editorial policy and stuff leaks through. Some of it hilariously bad. [The article you linked in a comment below](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-magicians-stl-algorithms/) is giving reasonable advice, but needs a bit of a working over to clean up the terminology and improve clarity and make some minor corrections. The code sample for `std::distance` leaves out the `<iterator>` header that declares `std::distance` and won't always compile. And in this case the omission lead you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ standard library josuttis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normative specification of everything in the standard library is in the C++ standard document.

> The one on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm does not include for example std::distance() defined in `<iterator>`.

Indeed, the linked page lists everything defined / declared in the header `<algorithm>` only. Standard functions defined / declared in the header `<iterator>` such as `std::distance` are listed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator.

A list of all standard library headers is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: There are also a few algorithms in `<numeric>`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Also in `<functional>` in the form of function objects.

Comment: Function objects are not algorithms. They're used by some algorithms.

Comment: @PeteBecker Function objects implement algorithms just as much as functions do. Only difference is that their algorithms can potentially be stateful.

Comment: STL algorithms operate on sequences of data designated by a pair of iterators. Function objects within the compass of the STL apply to a single data object. Yes, in a broad sense, functions might implement algorithms, but that’s outside the scope of the STL (that is, the Standard Template Library, not the STandard Library).